# How to hide <jdoc:include type="component" /> on the home page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, templates

I am working with a unique template index.php file and want to remove the `<jdoc:include type="component" />` because I don't want to display the empty space on the home page.

Answer (score 2):

In your `index.php`, you can use the following:

```
<?php $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu(); ?>
<?php if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

All this basically does is check if the active menu item **doesn't** match the default menu item. If it doesn't, display the component view.

Comment: @Ana Please provide constructive feedback so that this volunteer can perhaps modify the advice to resolve your issue.  You are welcome to edit your question to provide more information, a screenshot, and/or a link to your live site.  If you wish to post your working solution, the way to do that is to post an answer (not write it as a comment). Please take the [tour].  If `if ($app->getMenu()->getActive()->home != 1) { ?> <jdoc:include type="component" /> <?php }` works, then post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Lodder Thanks, but I had tried it and it does not work. After different test I found the solution, maybe is not a best practices but this work.

In your index.php

```
In line 20 before <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <?php
      $menu = $app->getMenu();
      $active = $menu->getActive();
      $homeactive = $active->home;
    ?>

In the Body:
    <?php if ($homeactive != 1) : ?>
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```